# BIND9 Version 9.11.33 dns delegation for Iodine tunnel

Tags: windows, networking, dns, bind, iodine

I'm trying to set up a DNS delegation using the production version of Bind9 (BIND9.11.33). The current zone is "example.localnet". The sub domain that I'm trying to set up for the Iodine DNS tunnelling is "dnstun.example.localnet".

The "example.localnet" domain points to a nameserver "ns1.example.localnet" with an IP address of "192.168.0.13". This is the IP of the DNS server. The delegated sub domain "dnstun.example.localnet" points to a nameserver "ns2.example.localnet" with an IP address of "192.168.0.14". This is were the Iodine server is located.

This is the interesting part: when I use NSLookup to query the Bind9 DNS server for "example.localnet" under set type=ns it gives the name server with the IP address. For the delegated sub domain it gives either NXDOAMIN, times out or server failure.

I noticed under Wireshark when I query NS for "dnstun.example.localnet" it goes to the internet to find out who is NS "dnstun.example.localnet". This returns NXDOMAIN.

Disabling forwarding and recursion the NS query for "dnstun.example.localnet" works perfectly fine. I'm not sure what exactly what I am missing. I also added a null forwarder to the "example.localnet" zone (in the named.conf) however it did not work. It either times out or server failure.

Here is my "named.conf" file:

```
options {
    directory "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    recursion yes;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 192.168.0.254; };
};

zone "example.localnet" IN {
    type master;
    file "db.example.localnet.txt";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    //  forwarders {};
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "db.192.168.0.txt";
};
```

Here is my "example.localnet" zone file:

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN SOA  ns1.example.localnet.   admin.example.localnet. (
        2005022201
        10800
        3600
        604800
        86400 )

@       NS  ns1.example.localnet.

ns1     IN A    192.168.0.13
dnstun  IN NS   ns2.example.localnet.
ns2     IN A    192.168.0.14
```

The reverse zone works fine. What I'm not sure is why the sub domain delegation does to resolve in the way that it should. I looked in the web for countless examples but could not get very far. I tried doing this exact same setup in Microsoft Server 2019 Datacentre and it works. No problems. Iodine DNS tunnel had no problems going through it.

Please let me know what I'm missing or what I am doing wrong so that I can learn from. Any pointers / help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Fixed. Even though NSLookup fails Iodine Server and Iodine Client manages to tunnel via the Bind DNS server. By adding this code "forwarders {};" in the zone "example.localnet" in named.conf it fixes the problem. Link: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX124727.

Here is my "named.conf" file:

```
options {
directory "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc";
allow-transfer { none; };
allow-query { any; };
recursion yes;
//  edns yes;
edns-udp-size 4096;
max-udp-size 4096;
forward only;
forwarders { 192.168.0.254; };
};

zone "example.localnet" IN {
type master;
file "db.example.localnet.txt";
allow-transfer { none; };
notify no;
forwarders {};
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "db.192.168.0.txt";
};
```

Here is my "example.localnet" zone file:

```
$TTL 6h
$ORIGIN example.localnet.
@   IN SOA  ns1.example.localnet.   admin.example.localnet. (
        2005022201
        10800
        3600
        604800
        86400 )

@       NS  ns1.example.localnet.


ns1 IN A    192.168.0.13
dnstun  IN NS   ns2.example.localnet.
ns2 IN A    192.168.0.14
```

Hope this helps somebody who might have a similar problem.